# Confusion matrix in R

Tags: r

Im having a little trouble with a confusion matrix. Has anyone had this issue before? I checked the observations and they are the same

```
library(e1071) # Please install the package first before running library syntax

Svm_Model = svm(t.total_hbat ~ t.inbound_calls_tied + 
              t.hbat_on_tickets_closed_by_agent + 
              t.inb_customer_hold_time, 
            Test_Data,
            kernel="linear",
            cost=.1,
            Scale=F)

Svm_Prediction = predict(Svm_Model,Test_Data,type="class")
View(as.data.frame(Svm_Prediction))

data_final<-cbind(Test_Data,Svm_Prediction)

confusionMatrix(table(Test_Data$t.total_hbat,Svm_Model))

Console:
confusionMatrix(table(Training_Data$t.total_hbat,Svm_Model))
Error in table(Training_Data$t.total_hbat, Svm_Model) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: `Svm_Model` is your model object, not the predictions. Try `table(Test_Data$t.total_hbat, Svm_Prediction)`.

Comment: When trying that formula I get the following error:

confusionMatrix(table(Test_Data$t.total_hbat,Svm_Prediction))

Console:
Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type